# Pipe output of one iteration of a python for loop to another script

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, docker, pipe

Each instance of the for loop, spits out the contents of one binary file which should be captured by another script to do further processing. For example:

script1.py

```
filename = glob.glob('*.txt')
for i in range(len(filename)):
    with open(filename[i], 'rb') as g:
        sys.stdout.write(g.read())
```

script2.py

```
from subprocess import call
script = "cat > test.fil"
call(script,shell=True)
```

Command:

```
python script1.py | python script2.py
```

If I execute this command, it waits for all iterations to be completed before piping the output to script2.py. I would like this to be done batchwise. For example, once data from one binary file is pushed to stdout, launch script2.py.

**script2.py cannot be called from script1.py. Both the scripts need to be run in different docker containers**. It would be better to avoid a docker installation inside a docker container.

Comment: Why not just read `stdin` directly in the second script instead of trying to use the shell to do it? (You could do it with the shell, although you haven't hooked it up to `stdin`, but I'd call that the most [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) I've ever seen.)

Comment: `script2.py` is going to see the same, continuous stream of bytes regardless of how `script1.py` writes them. You aren't going to be able to reliably distinguish between bytes from different files without some additional bytes injected into, and parsed from, the output of `script1.py`.

Comment: @chepner, can you please give me an example of what might work?

Comment: @kindall You are right, I can use stdin directly rather than use cat but I would like script2 to reliably distinguish different files like what chepner has indicated. Do you know how this could be done?

Comment: There are two options: if you know if a string that *cannot* appear in any input file, you can simply write that to the output stream between files. Otherwise, a safer idea is to write the file size to the stream *before* the file, so that a consumer knows that after reading a file size, the next X bytes are all part of the same file. After reading that many bytes, the next input should be another file size. Basically, you need some sort of protocol for encoding multiple files into one stream that both `script1.py` and `script2.py` will agree on.

Answer (score 2):

if `sys.stdout` is connect to a pipe, by default it buffers. You must call `sys.stdout.flush()` to flush the output:

```
sys.stdout.write(g.read())
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Your second script could also read stdin directly, instead of evoking the shell, to evoke cat, to read it. The way you wrote, you're executing 3 processes (python, your shell, cat).

```
import shutil
import sys
with open('test.fil', 'w') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(sys.stdin, f)
```

In a unrelated note, you **don't** need to use the `for` loop in a numeric `range`, when you are going to use the number only to index a `list`. The `for` loop can iterate directly in the `list` elements:

```
filenames = glob.glob('*.txt')
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as g:
        ...
```

Comment: The only thing `flush` will do is force output if a file is smaller than the pipe buffer. It's not going to help the second script identify bytes that are from one particular fiile.

Comment: @nosklo You are right that i need not use cat but is there a way for script2 to reliably distinguish between different files like the way chepner mentioned.